# Jackson, hashed password not being mapped

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper, mongojack

I have the following collection "player"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5426efb844ae829d1dcdaa6d"),
    "username" : "Foobar",
    "password" : "0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33",
    "gameIds" : [
            "5426f10544ae8502f731d8a0"
    ]
}
```

It has a hashed password.
When I try to map til back to my Player object, everything except the password is being mapped. The password is null.

This is my Player  with mappings

```
@Data
@JsonRootName("player")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {
    @JsonIgnore
    public static final String COL_NAME = "player";

    @ObjectId
    @Id
    private String id;

    /**Will use this token to authorize the user. This UUID should be cached once the user logs in */
    @JsonIgnore
    private UUID token = UUID.randomUUID();

    @NotBlank
    //Unique
    private String username;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    /** Set of unique active games * */
    private Set<String> gameIds = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I am saving the player like this:

```
    Player player = new Player();
    player.setUsername(username);
    player.getGameIds().add(pbfId);
    player.setPassword(DigestUtils.sha1Hex("foo"));
    playerCollection.insert(player);
```

And reading like this:

```
DBCursor<Player> username = playerCollection.find(DBQuery.is("username", "Foobar"), new BasicDBObject());
Player player = username.next();
```

Here everything except the password is correctly mapped

Comment: Where is Jackson involved here?

Comment: Mongojack uses it internally

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened, but seems like I queried the wrong database. I have no idea how this happened.

After going against the correct database, it worked fine